# Editing and compiling files on a remote server with Vim

Tags: ssh, vim, scp

I am editing a bunch of files on a remote server. I can connect using SSH (public key or password). I use Vim as follows:

`vim scp://user@server//path/to/file.cpp`

I need to use Vim on my computer because it is customized, thus I don't want to use the Vim installed on the server.

I can't install anything on this remote server. To compile, I run `make`.

I'd like to be able to run `make` from Vim so that it compiles on the server. I'd like to avoid opening another terminal with a SSH connection to that server.

My question then is: **is it possible to maintain a SSH connection through Vim?**

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered `scp -r ~/.vim user@example.com:`?  This would work well as long as your local and remote versions of Vim are reasonably close to one another.  Running `vim scp://...` has many limitations.

Comment: Yes but I have many Vim plugins which depend on external libraries. As I said, I cannot install anything.
What limitations do you see in using Vim the way I do?

Comment: For example you won't be able to run `:make`.

Comment: The trick is to run `:! ssh myserver 'make'`. Works amazingly well with @Enzo's solution.

Comment: Sure, but the reason most people run `:make` as opposed to running `make` at a shell's prompt is to let Vim parse errors from `makeprg` and subsequently open a quickfix window.  `:! ssh myserver 'make'` doesn't allow that. _shrug_

Comment: `:set makeprg=! ssh myserver 'make` is actually what I use. Works perfectly. A quickfix window is opened every time the compilation fails.

Comment: Great.  Now try opening a file from the quickfix window obtained that way. :)

Comment: Good point but in my case it's still a better and more convenient solution than using `scp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is as long as you are on a recent OpenSSH installation on the client.
You have the "control pipes" and `man ssh_config` will show you the *magics*.
Basically on the client you'd create a Host entry in `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host my_remote_server # a symbolic name of your choice
  Hostname server_IP_or_DNS # the real name
  User username # the username you use for login
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/a_suitable_ssh_key_if_any # for authentication purposes
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/%C # or ~/.ssh/%h-%p-%r for older versions
    ControlPersist 5m # or yes for neverexpiring persistent connection
```

By doing so the first connection will open a "channel" that will be kept open for the specified amount of time or forever.
From now on you can refer to your `ssh` connection with just the name you put as `Host`. So, for example, instead of writing:

```
vim scp://username@server_IP_or_DNS//full_path/to/file.cpp
```

you will write:

```
vim scp://my_remote_server//full_path/to/file.cpp
```

or

```
ssh my_remote_server
```

To kill an existing persistent connection you need to run:

```
ssh -O exit my_remote_server
```

All this will work for plain SSH, SCP and SFTP as well.
That'd be it.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm.

Comment: You can also mod my answer up! ;-)